# DLL Injection | GetProcAddress return NULL

Tags: c++, winapi, dll-injection

Alright, I'll try to make it quick. I am trying to learn how to inject a DLL in another process. At the moment, I'm only trying to detect when output a message when I open the calculator. I'v written the following DLL:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
extern "C"{
    LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {       
       cout << "I'M NOT WORKING " << endl;
       // Bunch of code...
       return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    } 
    void ASimpleFunc(){
        cout << "DLL WORKING" << endl;
    }
}
```

And here is my injector (well... it's just trying to load the DLL at the moment).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
typedef LRESULT (*CBTProc)(int,WPARAM,LPARAM); 
typedef void (*ASimpleFunc)(); 
int main()
{   
    // My two functions... 
    LRESULT _CBTProc;
    ASimpleFunc _ASimpleFunc;

   HMODULE hDll = LoadLibrary("myDLL.dll");
   if(!hDll){
       cout << "DLL FAILED TO LOAD" << endl;
   }else{
       cout << "DLL LOAD SUCCESS" << endl;

       // This one is working
       _ASimpleFunc = (ASimpleFunc)GetProcAddress(hDll, "ASimpleFunc");

       // This one is not working
        _CBTProc = (CBTProc)GetProcAddress(hDll, "CBTProc");
        if(!_ASimpleFunc || !_CBTProc){
            cout << "UNABLE TO CALL HOOK" << endl;
        }else{
            // other code...
        }
    }
   return 1;
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: this is not 100% of the code. I took out the obvious stuff like the DLLMain and everything that doesn't interact directly with my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `CALLBACK` macro gives `CBTProc` stdcall calling convention, so its name will be annotated with a leading underscore and a byte count (e.g., it might be `_CBTProc@12`).  You need to call `GetProcAddress` with the exact name of the export.  The name can be found using the dumpbin tool.

Note that your function pointer must also be annotated with `CALLBACK` so that when you call the function via the function pointer, the correct calling convention is used.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the @12 bit? Is it the size of the argument frame?

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually get the DLL to load in the other process for this to work. You do this by creating a remote thread in the other process that will load your DLL.

Then you need to perform your hooks in the loading of the `DLLMain` to hook the functions you wish to hook.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection

Those two links should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Ok, I didn't put the DLLMain because it seem obvious it was in there. However what you mean is that I should only use GetProcAddress for the DLLMain and DLLMain should be the one calling CPTProc. 

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you perform the hooks in the remote process in the `DLLMain`. You get the remote process to call the `DLLMain` by calling `CreateRemoteThread` on the other process using the `LoadLibraryA` and passing your DLL to that function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why one of them would work without this, but if you want a function to be exported from a DLL, you have to explicitly export it. There are two ways to do this:

1. **Tell the compiler** through some compiler-specific means.

   For **Visual C++**, [use `__declspec(dllexport)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx).
2. **[Use a module definition file.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx)**

Comment: Oh, I just didn't want to put too much code (like the DLLMain) I use cygwin compiler and export it manualy. I'm not too familiar with c++ yet so I'm doing my best with what I can put my  hand on.

Comment: @Michael: Can you edit your question to include the DEF file then?